# Average value form column - mySQL

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
+----+---------+------+----------+
| ID | ID_USER | NOTE | QUESTION |
+----+---------+------+----------+
|  1 |    12   |   3  |     1    |
|  2 |    31   |   2  |     1    |
|  3 |    12   |   9  |     1    |
|  4 |    31   |   8  |     2    |
|  5 |    12   |  10  |     2    |
|  6 |    31   |   3  |     2    |
+----+---------+------+----------+
```

How do I export values to group them by ID_USER, QUESTION and making an average of notes? The values to be grouped as in the table below:

```
+----+----------+---------+-------------+
| ID | QUESTION | ID_USER | MEDIUM_NOTE |
+----+----------+---------+-------------+
|  1 |     1    |    12   |       6     |
|  2 |     1    |    31   |       2     |
|  3 |     2    |    12   |       10    |
|  4 |     2    |    31   |      5.5    |
+----+----------+---------+-------------+
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please try this query? 

SELECT QUESTION, ID_USER, AVG(NOTE) AS MEDIUM_NOTE FROM table_name GROUP BY QUESTION, ID_USER;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    id_user,
    question,
    AVG(note) AS medium_note
FROM notes 
GROUP BY id_user, question
```

You can group by user and question, then calculate the average.

[Example](http://SELECT%20%20%09id_user,%20%09question,%20%09AVG(note)%20FROM%20notes%20%20GROUP%20BY%20id_user,%20question)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming id column is unique :

```
SELECT id,question,id_user,avg(note) as 'MEDIUM_NOTE' FROM table_name GROUP BY id_user,question ORDER BY id;
```